# Getting 500 error on webpage only for one computer

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I am running a site on php with a mysql backend. Things have been fine but suddenly one users account started getting a 500 error. Each user has his own profile when they log into the any box so his internet explorer settings are the same no matter what box he logs on to. Does anyone know if this could be an internet explorer setting causing this? I have tried to debug everything on the client side and no matter what I do he is getting rejected. No other account is having this issue. I am not really an SA but the only thing I think it can be at this point is some setting within his profile which is causing this. This is also happening on firefox but instead of a 500 error I am getting a blank white screen. (I assume friendly error messages are turned on)

Comment: The only reliable way to tell is to get hold of the Web server's error logs and check the error message. Apache's error messages (if it's Apache you're using) are quite good. Everything else we can do is just guesswork at this point.

Comment: 500 is an internal server error, nothing to do with the browser. You might have more luck on severfault

Comment: This question is better for ServerFault.

Comment: Thanks I did not know this site existed

Answer (score 1):

The issue had to do with a permission not properly set in one of the log folders. The system was trying to write to the log folder and for some reason that particular user was not set to have write access. The problem was impossible to track down but thanks for the help.

Comment: Your explanation of the cause of the issue somewhat proves that the problem wasn't quite as impossible to track down as you seem to suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If this is programming related, it might help turning error displaying on in php, using [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php):

```
<? error_reporting(E_ALL); ?>
```

Could be the browser acting up, sending weird headers or mangling requests because of addons or malware.